# Concatenating on Windows throws "Invalid data found when processing input" while it works on Mac and Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I need to run a command with a nightly build of FFMPEG to report a bug on the `concat` protocol. I found it difficult to compile from source with libx264 support on Linux, and I want to spare my Mac computer, so I use the nightly build on Windows from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

I call this command to concatenate the files:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 concat -i files_to_combine -vcodec libx264 show.mp4
```

where `files_to_combine` is:

```
file ./short_DSC_0013.MOV
file ./short_DSC_0014.MOV
file ./short_DSC_0015.MOV
file ./short_DSC_0016.MOV
file ./short_DSC_0017.MOV
file ./short_DSC_0018.MOV
file ./short_DSC_0019.MOV
```

I call this command from the directory containing the video files and `files_to_combine`.

On Windows with a nightly build, I get the error:

```
files_to_combine: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I changed `file ./DSC_0013.MOV` to these options, all with the same error:

```
file 'short_DSC_0013.MOV'
file '.\short_DSC_0013.MOV'
file 'F:\short_DSC_0013.MOV'
```

How can I debug this error, or what is the syntax for concatenating on Windows with a nightly build?

### Update with log-level 48

I ran the same command with `-v 48` and got:

```
F:\brain squids>C:\Users\migue\Desktop\ffmpeg-20200211-f15007a-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe -v 48 -i files_to_combine -vcodec libx264 show.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2020-02-11-f15007a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 39.100 / 56. 39.100
  libavcodec     58. 68.102 / 58. 68.102
  libavformat    58. 38.100 / 58. 38.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 75.100 /  7. 75.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument '48'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'files_to_combine'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option 'show.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option v (set logging level) with argument 48.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url files_to_combine.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: files_to_combine.
[NULL @ 0000021c781784c0] Opening 'files_to_combine' for reading
[file @ 0000021c78179580] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0000021c781817c0] Statistics: 182 bytes read, 0 seeks
files_to_combine: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The contents of `files_to_combine` is:

```
file 'short_DSC_0013.MOV'
file 'short_DSC_0014.MOV'
file 'short_DSC_0015.MOV'
file 'short_DSC_0016.MOV'
file 'short_DSC_0017.MOV'
file 'short_DSC_0018.MOV'
file 'short_DSC_0019.MOV'
```

### Update because of wrong command

I had mistyped the command. The right command has a `-f` in front of `concat`, which I found because the accepted answer was able to make the command work in a similar environment:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i files_to_combine -vcodec libx264 show.mp4
```

Comment: Share full log with loglevel 48

Comment: @Gyan I used `-v 48`, is that what you suggested?

Comment: Does the text file have an extension? Did you try `files_to_combine.txt`?

Comment: @drake7 The text file does not have an extension. I get the same result when I change the name of the source file to `files_to_combine.txt` in the filesystem and the command, either with or without `-v 48`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tested it successfully on Windows 10:**

(ffmpeg version `N-95216-ge6625ca41f`)

1. Videos `01.mp4`, `02.mp4`and `.txt` are in `C:\Users\drake7\Desktop\`
2. Content of `files_to_combine.txt`:

_

```
file 'C:\Users\drake7\Desktop\01.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\drake7\Desktop\02.mp4'
```

*Note:* `02.mp4` *is a copy of* `01.mp4`*. For this quick test I wanted to keep it really simple.*

`.txt` *created with* `right-click > New > Text Document`

(With my windows command prompt I am in `C:\Users\drake7\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin`)

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:\Users\drake7\Desktop\files_to_combine.txt" -vcodec libx264 "C:\Users\drake7\Desktop\show.mp4"
```

Comment: This was my fault and I apologize. The problem was that I use Windows for video production (because of AviSynth) and a mac computer for everything else, and I had missed the `-f concat` when typing the command. The error is now gone and I updated the question.